# sts/eclipse lock the versioned jar and hence ivy does not resolve dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, ivy

In my Project, I am using snapshot revision of jar referencing to other project like:

> <
>   dependency org= "com.myproject"   name="edo-common" rev="3.0.0-SNAPSHOT" transitive="false" changing="true">

When i try to resolve ivy, it tries to delete old versioned jar and replace it by new one. But STS locks the versioned jar and does not allow to remove the old jar. 
So ivy gives error of not resolving the dependency.

What could be the way so that STS/eclipse does not lock the jar?

Please help.

Comment: What is STS? Eclipse won't lock the jar. Running processes that use the jar will lock it.

Comment: STS is SpringSource Tool Suite based on Eclipse. As mentioned by oers, I think your app server might be still running. Just stop the server and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by updating the ivy version and I got one option there as:
delete old retreive artifacts in classpath of ivy.xml
And also if you want to load jar from your lib you can select the option as:
Build the classpath with:
select
      retreived artifacts
It will not lock the jar while taking the updates.